# QODBC connecting to Python

Tags: python, pyodbc, quickbooks, qodbc

I am using QODBC Driver to connect to my Quickbooks Data. Until now, I was the QODBC directly in Power BI/Excel and QODBC works perfectly fine there. But today, I tried to connect to QODBC using python and it is giving me the following error
[image]

The python code I am using is this

```
import pyodbc 

cn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=QuickBooks Data 64-Bit QRemote;')
cursor = cn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Top 10 Name FROM Customer")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)

cursor.close()

cn.close()
```

Can anyone see what's the reason for this error?

Comment: Just a guess, but you could try setting `pyodbc.pooling = False` before calling `pyodbc.connect()` and see if that helps.

Comment: @GordThompson, no bro it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of googling, I found the answer. I don't know why but the pyodbc.connect statement requires one more parameter i.e. "autocommit=True". So, the updated code now looks like this and it is working perfectly fine.

```
import pyodbc 

# pyodbc.pooling = False
cn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=QuickBooks Data 64-Bit QRemote',autocommit=True)
cursor = cn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT Top 10 Name FROM Customer")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)

cursor.close()

cn.close()
```